# Custom Swipeable View in Android

Tags: android, swipe-gesture

I want to create a swipe-able view for showing status of user. When user swipes status should change from active to inactive or vice versa. And I want this view to be only at max 70-80 dp in height.
How can I achieve this behavior ??

Comment: Google Search Please

Comment: done that I only find view pager for doing this kind of task but that doesn't suit my needs

Comment: Good to hear .Move ahead .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/animation/screen-slide.html) .

> It have built-in swipe gestures to transition through pages, and they
>   display screen slide animations by default, so you don't need to
>   create any. ViewPagers use PagerAdapters as a supply for new pages to
>   display .

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

- [Android ViewPager Example](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/)

Comment: I tried using view pager but that doesn't fit properly with the view.
Half of the text from next option was also visible with the first one

Comment: @VivekMishra Okay .Can you provide Screen shots ?

Comment: Thanks this tutorial helped me alot and have done what I wanted. May be that i was doing saomething wrong